# Batch to rename folder with file

Tags: windows, rename

i have one big folder with many folders with some files, like this:

```
FOLDER
img 08-21
- japan.jpg; 
- german.jpg;
- london.jpg;

img 08-22
- caribic.jpg
- malta.jpg

ims 08-23
- center.jpg
- circle.jpg
- bike.jpg
```

and i want to rename by batch(.bat or whatever for winXP cmd) to

```
FOLDER
01-img 08-21
- 01-japan.jpg
- 01-german.jpg
- 01-london.jpg

02-img 08-22
- 02-caribic.jpg
- 02-malta.jpg

03-ims 08-23
- 03-center.jpg
- 03-circle.jpg
- 03-bike.jpg
```

I want to rename folder to prefix(number)-folder and files (in folder) to prefix(folder)-file. 
Can somebody pls help me?

Answer (score 4):

The following batch file should solve this. Explanations follow below.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set counter=0
for /d %%d in (*) do (
    set /a counter+=1
    call :lz
    pushd %%d
    for %%f in (*) do ren "%%f" "!counter!-%%f"
    popd
    ren "%%d" "!counter!-%%d"
)
endlocal
goto :eof
:lz
set counter=000%counter%
rem adapt this to allow for three-digit numbering
set counter=%counter:~-2%
goto :eof
```

Basically this loops over all directories with

```
for /d %%d in (*)
```

The `/d` switch here is for looping only over directories. The current directory within the loop is stored in `%%d`. Then the counter (which is set to 0 at the start) is incremented by one and padded appropriately at the start with zeroes if necessary. This is done by the call to the `:lz` subroutine. Within that subroutine (it's at the end of the batch) the number of digits can be changed in the line

```
set counter=%counter:~-2%
```

by changing the `2` to `3` or so.

Then the directory will be changed to the one we're currently handling using `pushd` (which has the nice property that we can *undo* this directory change afterwards by using `popd`) and another loop is performed, this time over the files inside the directory:

```
for %%f in (*) do ren "%%f" "!counter!-%%f"
```

which renames the files and prepends the counter value to them. The exclamation marks around the counter variable name are so-called *delayed expansion* which is necessary here (why this is so can be read up in `help set`).

After renaming all files in the directory we jump out of it again and rename the directory itself. Nothing too fancy here.

Comment: Nice answer. Good explanations too!